# Am I adding yet another, or changing, this constraint?

Tags: ios, swift3, nslayoutconstraint

Say I do this ...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
```

later, I do this ...

```
view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 51).isActive = true
```

am I a bad person?

Have I now redundantly added a second constraint (what happens to the first?)

Or does it know to change the first?

Or does something else happen?  Am I making a leak?

What should I do, and in what way have I been bad, if any?

What's the correct thing to do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
> ```
>
> later, I do this ...
>
> ```
> view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 51).isActive = true
> ```
>
> am I a bad person?

Yes, and if I'm not mistaken, the runtime will tell you so with a loud message in the console warning that you have unsatisfiable (conflicting) constraints. You have a constraint setting the height to 50 and another setting the height to 51 and both things cannot be true.

You didn't give enough code to be sure of what's going on in your case, but you can easily see that what I'm saying is correct, by making your view controller's code consist only of the following:

```
func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(v)
        v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        delay(3) {
            v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 51).isActive = true
        }
    }

}
```

As you stipulated, we "later" add the 51 constraint — and as I said, the runtime squawks at that moment.

The correct procedure is to *keep a reference* to the original constraint
so that you can change its `constant` later. (Under more complex circumstances you could actually deactivate, i.e. remove, the first constraint before adding the second, but if all you plan to do is alter the `constant`, that's not necessary, as it is mutable.)

Comment: Matt, could he leave his code as is and just call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` after he changes the constraint??

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog No. He didn't change any constraint (nor did he replace a constraint). He added a second height constraint. That's my point.

Comment: Is there no way to access this view's constraint to update it without creating a reference to it? I'm just curious to the best use case here.  If I needed to update 5 different constraints then I wouldn't want to have 5 separate references for each individual constraint

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog Very good question. In my experience there is no good way. You can't readily say to a view "please hand me your height constraint so I can change it". It feels often as if there should be a way, but there is not, presumably because things are not as simple as that. In real life, many things can go into determining a view's height.

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog Thus we end up using techniques as in my example here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/dddb3d4c21e553c18bb6144f3784c2223011e3d1/bk2ch01p041constraintSwapping2/ConstraintSwapping/ViewController.swift keeping references to entire sets of constraints so we can swap them in and out nimbly.

Comment: hey @matt - totally understood, thanks.  you know, bizarrely, *I am not seeing any warnings*.  {Random thought: I wonder if it could have to do with the wonderful world of stack views.}  {Another idea: I'm doing the first one in viewDidLoad ("most of these are 50 high"); a few special ones get set to 51 - but (perhaps, I'd have to investigate) they get set to 51 before layout. Maybe that explains why seemingly no error. I don't know.}  Anyways, thanks again.

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog .. right; indeed it's trivial to keep a constraint; so that's the way to go.  BTW .. roll tide  :)

Comment: @JoeBlow I added code that shows the problem in action.